# OpenCV Python laser dot tracking extracting x and y coordinates and store it to different variables

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKiyU.png)I have a code here that tracks a laser dot.What I want is to get the x and y coordinates of the laser dot and store it to separate variables. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (1):

    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 0, 255])
    upper_red = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('Track Laser', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you show us an image? (Input/output) It's hard to do image processing without one. :)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq done

Answer (score 1):

For multiple points or noisier data, you might want to consider clustering algorithms.

However, the image you attached is quite clear. All you need to do is find the center of it. That corresponds the the first geometrical moment (aka mean):

```
moments = cv2.moments(hsv[:, :, 2])
x = int(moments['m10'] / moments['m00'])
y = int(moments['m01'] / moments['m00'])
```

This lets us find the center fairly accurately, provided there are no outliers (e.g. noise or other circles) affecting the distribution.

[image]

---

Perhaps a more robust method (to noise and number of circles) would make use of Hough circles.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It looks like a circle because it's near from the webcam. I doubt if it will still look like a circle from a far. But still, Thank you.

Comment: can i talk to you privately?